# Why am I receiving this strcpy assignment error if the two variables I am assigning to each other are both of type string?

Tags: c++, string, strcpy

I'm getting this error:

```
error: cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'char* strcpy(char*, const char*)'
```

Which I assume means it is unable to assign my one title string to my newtitle string, because they are not of the same type. (one being char and the other const char I suppose?)

```
strcpy(title, newtitle);
```

But they are both defined as type string, so I'm a little confused as to what it is that is giving me this error. Although I could be wrong about what this error means exactly.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
#include <cstring>


class Movie{
private:
string title;
int year;
string director;

public:
void setTitle(string);  // function prototype
void setYear(int);  // function prototype
void setDirector(string);   // function prototype

void displayMovie();    // function prototype
};


void Movie::setTitle(string newtitle)   
{

strcpy(title, newtitle);    

}


int main()
{

Movie myMovie;
string movietitle;


cout << "Enter the title of the Movie: " << endl;
cin >> movietitle;

myMovie.setTitle(movietitle);


}
```

Comment: You don't need `strcpy` for `std::string` variables. You need that for the old, C-style strings, that are effectively a simple array of `char`s. `std::string` is a much more complex class, and it supports direct assignment, like `title = newtitle;`.

Comment: This code won't reproduce the error.  Make a complete example that reproduces your error.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: The question is about a fatal compile-time error. But you're right, there's another error in this code that prevents the reported error message from showing up.

Comment: Nit, and updated...it still doesn't reproduce the error.

Comment: @MarkTolonen This is the entire code I have so far, and I get this error. According to people below its because you cannot assign two strings together using that function.

Comment: It's not the code that reproduces the error, because without `void Movie::setTitle` it will return something along the lines of `title not defined`.  Plus no `#include <iostream>`, `#include <string>`, and at least `using namespace std;`.  Cut and paste the actual file that causes the error.  We know what is wrong in this case, but still...good practice so people trying to help don't have to do more work.

Comment: Oh right, I added the Movie:: to setTitle after because I was getting an error saying title wasn't declared in the scope, I must have copied and pasted the un-updated code onto here, but with the Movie::setTitle I lose the undeclared error and gain the one I currently am I having trouble with.

Answer (score 6):

[`std::strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) expects its 1st argument to be `char*`, but [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) couldn't be implicitly converted to `char*`, that's why compiler complains.

You don't need to use `strcpy` for `std::string`, you could just

```
title = newtitle;
```

Comment: I know its possible to do it this way but this is homework I'll admit, and it's fairly easy except the fact that she wants us to use that function, which is the only thing I've gotten stuck at so far because of this error

Comment: @Dante, you can't use `strcpy` to copy a `std::string` into a `std::string`.  Are you supposed to be using `char` arrays instead?

Comment: @Dante Then you might use raw char array with `strcpy`. IMO, using raw char array instead of `std::string` in c++ doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Well in the email she sent everyone her example also used strings and the strcpy function. I've tried changing them to char before but I get more errors, she isn't a very good professor that is for sure.

Comment: @Dante As mark said, it's impossible to use `strcpy` to copy `std::string` into `std::string`. It's possible to use `strcpy` to copy `std::string` into raw `char` array.

Comment: @songyuanyao well it is possible, just not a good idea. You could write `d.resize( strlen(ptr) + 1 ); strcpy( &d[0], ptr ); d.resize( d.size() - 1 );`